# Count distinct node pairings in a multihop match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking to count the number of distinct pairings in query of neighbor's neighbors. Let say I have a small graph consisting of the following nodes and edges,

```
(id:A, type:1)->(id:B, type:2)
(id:A, type:1)->(id:C, type:2)
(id:B, type:2)->(id:D, type:3)
(id:C, type:2)->(id:D, type:3)
(id:C, type:2)->(id:E, type:3)
```

and a pattern to match like,

```
MATCH (n0 {id: A})--(n1:2)--(n2)
WHERE n2.id IN ["D", "E"]
```

I am looking for a query that will count the distinct pairings along this 2-hop pattern. In other words, the expected answer would give the counts,

```
A to type2   : 2 connections
type2 to D   : 2 connections
type2 to E   : 1 connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` and `type` are properties, this works:

```sql
MATCH (n0 {id: "A"})--(n1 {type:2})--(n2)
WHERE n2.id IN ["D", "E"]
WITH collect(DISTINCT [n0, n1]) AS r1, collect(DISTINCT [n1, n2]) AS r2
WITH 
    COLLECT {
        WITH r1
        UNWIND r1 AS r
        WITH r[0].id AS lhs, 'type' + r[1].type AS rhs, count(*) AS num
        RETURN {lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs, num: num }
    } AS first, 
    COLLECT {
        WITH r2
        UNWIND r2 AS r
        WITH 'type' + r[0].type AS lhs, r[1].id AS rhs, count(*) AS num
        RETURN {lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs, num: num }
    } AS second
UNWIND first + second AS cn
RETURN 
    cn.lhs + ' to ' + cn.rhs + ': ' + cn.num + 
    CASE 
      WHEN cn.num = 1 THEN ' connection' 
      ELSE ' connections' 
    END AS result
```

It's not pretty ...

Answer (score 0):

This query might suffice (it repeats the same `A_to_type2` count in each result row):

```
MATCH ({id: "A"})-[r1]-({type:2})-[r2]-(n2)
WHERE n2.id IN ["D", "E"]
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT r1) AS A_to_type2, COLLECT({n2Id: n2.id, r2: r2}) AS data
UNWIND data AS d
RETURN A_to_type2, d.n2Id AS n2Id, COUNT(DISTINCT d.r2) AS type2_to_n2Id
```

Output for your sample data:

```
╒══════════╤════╤═════════════╕
│A_to_type2│n2Id│type2_to_n2Id│
╞══════════╪════╪═════════════╡
│2         │"D" │2            │
├──────────┼────┼─────────────┤
│2         │"E" │1            │
└──────────┴────┴─────────────┘
```

Or, to return a single row with a collection of the type2_to_n2Id counts:

```
MATCH ({id: "A"})-[r1]-({type:2})-[r2]-(n2)
WHERE n2.id IN ["D", "E"]
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT r1) AS A_to_type2, COLLECT({n2Id: n2.id, r2: r2}) AS data
UNWIND data AS d
WITH A_to_type2, d.n2Id AS n2Id, COUNT(DISTINCT d.r2) AS cnt
RETURN A_to_type2, COLLECT({n2Id: n2Id, count: cnt}) AS type2_to_n2Id
```

Sample result:

```
╒══════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│A_to_type2│type2_to_n2Id                                 │
╞══════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│2         │[{count: 2, n2Id: "D"}, {count: 1, n2Id: "E"}]│
└──────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```